# Maven won't run my Project : Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-2, javafx

I can't run the Maven Netbeans JavaFX example :

```java
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) onproject mavenproject3:
  Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
  switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

My POM looks like this :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.huw.almexoffice.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>almex-office-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Almex Office Client</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.huw.almexoffice.client.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            
            
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

And if not, does anyone know how to get Maven running with the -e or the -X switch via Netbeans? I assume it is via a right click on the POM and then run goal then entering something in the textfield there.

Comment: how were you able to fix this issue? I'm also facing the same issue and given suggestions not working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

1. This error would spring up arbitrarily and caused quite a bit of trouble though the code on my end was solid.

I did the following :

- I closed it on netbeans.
- Then open the project by clicking "Open Project", selecting my project and
- Simply hit the run button in netbeans.

I would not build or clean build it. Hope that helps you out.

2. I noticed another reason why this happens. If you moved your main class to another package, the same error springs up. In that case you :

   - Right Click Project > Properties > Run
   - Set the "Main Class" correctly by clicking "Browse" and selecting.

Comment: Number 2 was my case. Good catch since I am a beginer it would have taken ages to find that out.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. When I tried to run the project from IDE, it was giving me same error. But when I tried running from the command prompt, the project was running fine. So it came to me that there should be some issue with the settings that makes the program to Run from IDE.

I solved the problem by changing some Project settings. I traced the error and came to the following part in my pom.xml file.

```
            <execution>
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>                            
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                    <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```

I went to my Project Properties > Actions Categories > Action: Run Project:
then I Set Properties for Run Project Action as follows:

```
runfx.args=-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
```

Then, I rebuild the project and I was able to Run the Project. As you can see, the IDE(Netbeans in my case), was not able to find 'runfx.args' which is set in Project Properties.

Comment: In my case, I had the problem with the version of the maven plugin (1.5.0) used by Netbeans 11.1 and I didn't know where to change this, you guided me to the right place
`Project Properties > Actions Categories > Action: Run Project`

Comment: You are a genius. I wish I could upvote this a million times!

Comment: @FiruzzZ what did you change it to?

Comment: @martinkimani  the action execution goals: Run project, run file via main() and any other action that you could use.
`process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec`

Answer (score 2):

1. what's happening? you haven' shown much of the output to be able to decide. if you are using netbeans 7.4, try disabling Compile on Save.
2. to enable debug output, either run Custom > Goals... action from project popup or after running a regular build, click the Rerun with options action from the output's toolbar

Comment: i still can't get it to show any decent output. Do you think it has anything to do with not being able to find the javafxpackager under the bin?

Comment: is possible. I've coworked on the archetype for javafx and honestly, there's no good way of handling javafx execution (unless there is a plugin for that I don't know about) The javafx people keep on changing stuff and didn't bother to a simple way to run javafx apps.

Comment: Had same problem on NetBeans 8.2. Disabling Compile on Save finally solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner in Maven - don't know much about it. 
Carefully check on your input i.e. file path in my case. 
After I have carefully check, my file path is wrong so it leads to this error.
After I fixed it, it works magically lol.

Comment: Same for me. I had to add a "/" at the start of the path.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which worked in my case is:
  1. Go to the module having Main class.
  2. Right click on pom.xml under this module.
  3. Select "Run Maven" -> "UpdateSnapshots"

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, I worked around it by changing
 ${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager
to 
${java.home}/bin/javafxpackager

Comment: This did not work for me.. Same error, even after Clean & Build.

Comment: I got mine to work: I had to add `.exe` to the original location so that it became: `${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem after installing oracle jdk on Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

I've done the following steps, not sure which one helped. I think that at least 2 and 3 are necessary.

1. Deleted Netbeans 7.4 and reinstalled it from oracle's site.
2. Installed plugins for maven, ant and java that may be related to the project.
3. Deleted .nbproject folder - after that the project was considered a maven project.

Also, after that, I've found that the project runs, but exits with exit code 1 because I didn't supply the command line parameters for it. And the builder considers it is an error. So, look carefully for the output and see if the program actually starts.

Answer (score 1):

Maven needs to be able to access various Maven repositories in order to download artifacts to the local repository. If your local system is accessing the Internet through a proxy host, you might need to explicitly specify the proxy settings for Maven by editing the Maven `settings.xml` file. **Maven builds ignore the IDE proxy settings that are set in the Options window.**
For many common cases, just passing `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` to Maven should suffice to download artifacts through the system's configured proxy. NetBeans 7.1 will offer to configure this flag for you if it detects a possible proxy problem. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194916 has discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with right click on project -> Set as Main Project.

Answer (score 1):

**Netbeans needs to be able to index the maven repository.** Allow it to do that and try again. It was giving me the same error and after it indexed the repository it ran like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Maven from the command line or type "-X" in the text field - you can't break anything this way, at the worst, you'll get an error (I don't have Netbeans; in Eclipse, there is a checkbox "Debug" for this).

When running with debug output enabled, you should see the paths which the exec-maven-plugin plugin uses.

The next step would then be to copy the command into a command prompt or terminal and execute it manually to see if you get a useful error message there.

Answer (score 0):

> Restart Netbeans & it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im new to java hibernate but i could solve this problem, this is how i did it :
I was working with hibernate and maven project.
First you have to put persistence.xml under project directory, then add jdbc manually.
Maven couldn't download my dependency so i added it manually.
In the persistence.xml in design jdbc connection add it manually ps: i work with netbeans good luck

Answer (score 0):

For me, the clue was the "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec".
The only place this was referenced was in the "Run project" action under Project Properties=>Actions.

When I changed this action to match the HelloFXMLWithMaven sample project (available in Netbeans 11.1):
"clean javafx:run"
then executing the Run goal was able to proceed.

Note, I also had to update the pom file's javafx-maven-plugin to also match the sample project but with the mainClass changed for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Rohith H.Y Solved this problem

2. I noticed another reason why this happens. If you moved your main class to another package, the same error springs up.

In that case you :

Right Click Project > Properties > Run
Set the "Main Class" correctly by clicking "Browse" and selecting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).