# How to run javaSE maven project on Netbeans with debug -X

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am getting a BUILD FAILURE when I try to **run** the project, if I do a clean and build there is no error.

Where do I have to add this `-X` or `-e` parameter to see where is the problem? My POM doesn't have any plugin defined.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.839 s
Finished at: 2020-08-27T10:54:32-03:00
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project validadorCliente: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>validadorCliente</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>jax-ws-catalog.xml</include>
                    <include>wsdl/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>localhost_8080/saos-validador/Validador310Service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <packageName></packageName>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/saos-validador/Validador310Service?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/Validador310Service.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-Validador310Service</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org</groupId>
            <artifactId>SAOS-backend</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
            <artifactId>hotswap-agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-spring-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-wildfly-el-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-tomcat-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-mojarra-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-jbossmodules-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-jersey1-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-jersey2-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-myfaces-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-owb-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-resteasy-registry-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-omnifaces-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-weld-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-zk-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-seam-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-deltaspike-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: `mvn clean package -X` is how you provide `-X` flag. Can you provide your pom.xml?

Comment: but that command just build it, there is no error building, the problem is when I try to RUN it

Comment: You have some custom dependencies which I can't have in my project. Like SAOS-Backend.

Comment: yes, that is the backend, where most @entity and DAO are, this project of for testing a Webservice `saos-validador` like you can see too. I just want to know where do I have to add IN netbeans the `-X`

Comment: Ah. you don't have build problems? but you were asking for `-X` and `-e` flags and said initially, that you were getting a *Build Problem*. Please edit your question and specify what exactly is a problem.

Comment: yes,  but even if it's not, the project works, the status of the WS is part of the testing to check

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin

1. Be sure that you use the latest version of the plugin (3.0.0 I think)
2. Check out [Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011494/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-2java-default-cli)

Comment: I tried that but got another exception, `Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)`

....
....
`BUILD FAILURE
Total time:  2.896 s
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project validadorCliente: Command execution failed.: `

Comment: Why do you use that plugin? Is it required?

Comment: It is how Netbeans runs every Maven java SE desktop app

Comment: Ok, I see. Check out these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077870/maven-wont-run-my-project-failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven

Comment: thanks, but I know that post, I gave some comments in the most voted answer a year ago ;), in those comments I mention how to change the plugin version, because every release of Netbeans update it by default and give some problems (that's why I still use 1.2.1, because always worked for me until now)

Comment: I see. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and never having build or run problems related with IDE. I was using NetBeans before, still using for databases. But for development I think IntelliJ is the best. However I will check out with one of my JavaFX projects! What's your Netbeans version?

Comment: the latest 12.0, I created a new project, the problem is when I create the WS Client, 2 of 4 ways that NB gives to create those throws a weird exception and after the WSDL and jaxws generated source is created the project doesn't RUN any more, but I can't see what it is failing, that's why I wanted to know where to add the `-X`. I will give it a try to IntellJ

Comment: Well I installed Netbeans 12 and tried one of its own demo projects DVDStoreAdmin (Maven+Swing+Hibernate). It doesn't even build because of very old library versions etc. But the most important thing is that I see that there is an nbactions.xml file which runs those goals. Then I created a new Swing app from a maven archetype (org.codehaus.griffon) which doesn't have that nbactions.xml file. And it runs without any error. Did you try to delete that nbactions.xml or remove those goals from your run configuration?

Comment: Another solution: add that -X to the nbactions.xml as shown in https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: tried to add in nbactions.xml `<properties><exec.args>-X ...` but I got **The -X options are non-standard and subject to change without notice** so I removed the file, I am still trying to define a Goal in the POM to run the project but notice that I wouldn't be able to use the debugger from the IDE this way

Comment: finally could ran with -e -X but nothing useful came up
[log](https://snipboard.io/yXR9cQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Properties > Actions > in the field **Execute goals**: `-e -X`

If you want to do it through Maven: `mvn -e -X "-Dexec.args= ....."`

PD: My problem had nothing to do with the IDE or Maven, I have a NPE and I was ignoring the exception

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        MainView vista = new MainView(null, true);
        vista.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace(); <--- HERE WAS THE PROBLEM
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

thank you Onur and Giorgi for your time